# There is no smallest rational number greater than 2

Tags: order-theory, rational-numbers

I have a problem that I am seriously stuck on. I'm not sure what to do I've seen similar proofs online with the least positive rational number but this is apparently different and I'm not sure why.

> Prove the statement “There is no smallest rational number greater than 2” by contradiction.

Comment: You don't have a proof, you have a problem. It's unnecessary to emphasize "proof" so much in tags and title: pretty much everything in mathematics is about proofs.

Comment: I agree but this requires us to have this as a proof, in proof format, and logically proven to be true or false.

Comment: *Everything*  ought to be logically proven to be true or false, when possible. The requirement of a proof may be unusual to you,  but it's not unusual in mathematics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose there was a smallest rational number greater than $2$. Call it $k =p/q$.

Then consider $ k' = \frac{2+k}{2}$. This is a number bigger than $2$ and less than $k$. Also $k'$ is rational. Therefore there is no smallest rational number greater than $2$.

Comment: Thank you I understand what your saying. I think I'll be able to write something up now.